# Long time C# MVC WebDev - should I be using .NET Core or is it case by case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

As the title says... I've been using C# MVC for most of my web dev needs for many years. We have a bunch of legacy systems here so my technology choices have been set in stone.

New system time! Looking at React, dotnetify seems cool but it pushes towards Core. Core is so very very different to what I'm used to. As an example, no FormsAuthentication.

I'm obviously fine with learning a new tech if that's what "everybody is doing" -- but are they? Or is the .NET world split between .NET 5 and Core?

Comment: There is no ASP.NET with .NET 5. If you want to use new ASP.NET features, then ASP.NET Core is the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, if your Application have dependency on Legacy Libraries and tools, which runs only on `Windows Server` for example `SQL Server Reporting Services`, there is no benefit of using `.Net Core` in terms of `cross platform` support

In such case, when there is dependency on legacy Libraries and tools, but you are still ready to deploy final application on Windows Server (and not targeting `Linux`)- then you can go ahead with `.Net Core`

Comment: Thanks for your input friend I appreciate it.